# AngularJS route stops working on a local port

Tags: angularjs

I am using AngularJS to build a web app. I use ngRoute  for routing and templating. I use gulp-serve to start my website locally. Once for few days it suddenly stops working. After I change local port it works ok.

For example: First it worked on port localhost:3000, but stopped and doesn`t work anymore
then the same with ports 3001,3002,3003,3004

Stopped working means it doesnt load template any more. If I try to access template file directly it is ok, but angular isnt loading it. In debug console there are no messages.

Can somebody explain how is it possible.

Answer (score 0):

I guess I am not in a position to give you a 100% perfect explanation of this issue, but I am assuming that somewhere in your gulp-serve config the default to serve your app is set to port:3000. By attempting to reach the other ports you listed your app is not loading...

Answer (score 0):

The problem was somewhere in cookies. After I clear cookie it goes ok. I use Auth0 service for logging. Maybe the problem is somewhere in their angularjs sdk.